# Retrofit: How to send value to REST API and check if it exists?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

First of all I'm playing with Retrofit for the first time in Kotlin Android.

**So the Logic i want is like this:**

1. I want send a **username** to the Rest API.
2. Then check if it is exists or not.
3. if it exists I want to make a Toast message saying **true** if it does not exist **False**.

So, I have this JSON in this URL:`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net"
  }
]
```

So let me walk through the content of my code using Retrofit

**Model.class**

```
class FakeUserModel {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username")
    val username: String = ""
}
```

**Retrofit Api Client** class

```
object FakeUserApiClient {
  var BASE_URL:String="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
  val getFakeUserClient: ApiInterface
    get() {

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

And this ApiInterface to demonstrate the fucntion to you are using to send data to the server:

**Api Interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {
     @FormUrlEncoded
     @POST("users")
     fun check( @Field("username") username:String ): Call<FakeUserModel>
}
```

So finally, in the Activity I want to receive the response telling me if it exists or not...

**Activity class**

```
checkButton.setOnClickListener {
    val username = userName.text.toString().trim()

    FakeUserApiClient.getFakeUserClient.check(username)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<FakeUserModel>{
            override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<FakeUserModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: retrofit2.Call<FakeUserModel>,
                response: Response<FakeUserModel>
            ) {
                if (response != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

        })
}
```

When I execute the app it always saying `true`, even if the username I have passed is not on the JSON... 
So, guys is there a problem in my code? What did I missed? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `response` is of a non-nullable type, so the condition `response != null` is always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this ApiInterface

```
interface ApiInterface {
 @GET("users")
 fun check( @Query("username") username: String ): Call<FakeUserModel>
}
```

When username is present you will get response like below
Url - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username=Bret

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
  "street": "Kulas Light",
  "suite": "Apt. 556",
  "city": "Gwenborough",
  "zipcode": "92998-3874",
  "geo": {
    "lat": "-37.3159",
    "lng": "81.1496"
  }
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
  "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
  "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
  "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
}  ]
```

When user name is not Present you will get empty response
Url - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username=Bre

```
[]
```

Comment: That makes sense, but it is still an `ArrayList` being returned... to map that, address, geo and company would need to be nested models.

Comment: Yaa, an empty arraylist is returned

Comment: thanks pal for your anwser, but it's showing `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column2`

Comment: Change your FakeUserModel. It should have List<User> where User is another model class in which you have id, name, username .etc

Comment: thanks man this help alot and by the way update your answer by removing `@FormUrlEncoded`, this worked for men.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the following two APIs -

1. **GET** https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
2. **POST** https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

First one is for getting a list of users. On the other hand, the second one is for posting a username in the request body as formUrlEncoded format which returns the same username and the corresponding id in JSON format. In your code, we can only see the usage of the 2nd API.

After analyzing the 2nd API I found that it always returns the same username that I post as a request body. Therefore it is pointless of checking, if the provided username matches with the username returned in the response.

> You might ask, will my code work if I confirm, there is no guarantee
>   that the provided username is always the same as the returning ones?

My answer would be **no**. Let me show you where did you make the mistake -

**Activity class**

```
checkButton.setOnClickListener {
    val username = userName.text.toString().trim()
        ...
                // The following condition is always true.
                if (response != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        ...
}
```

So, if you look into the above snippet in Android studio you might have noticed that the `if (response != null)` is highlighted saying it will always be true. Because the response object is the actual response containing response code, message, headers, body, etc. Practically, a body can be null but the entire response object can not be null.

To make your code working you need to compare the username that you provide in the request with the username you get in the response. You can accomplish this by replacing the if statement with the following code,

```
Toast.makeText(
        applicationContext,
        // If the response body is null return "false". 
        // In run block return "true" as it has an instance having same username that of the input.
        response.body()?.takeIf { it.username == username }?.run { "true" } ?: "false",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
).show()
```

> In case if I didn't understand your question completely. And what you wanted to accomplish was to send a
>   username by calling the 2nd API and obtain a list of users by
>   calling the 1st API to check if the username exists in the list. If
>   this is the case, then you need to need to perform following changes
>   in your code,

**API Interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("users")
    fun check( @Field("username") username:String ): Call<FakeUserModel>

    // Add following fun to get a list of FakeUserModel
    @GET("users")
    fun list() : Call<List<FakeUserModel>>
}
```

**Activity class**

```
checkButton.setOnClickListener {
val username = userName.text.toString().trim()
FakeUserApiClient.getFakeUserClient.apply {
        // First post the username
        check(username).enqueue(object : Callback<FakeUserModel>{
            ...
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<FakeUserModel>, response: Response<FakeUserModel>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    // username post request is successful. now get the user list
                    list().enqueue(object : Callback<List<FakeUserModel>>{
                        ...
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<FakeUserModel>>, response: Response<List<FakeUserModel>>) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                response.body()?.run {
                                    // this block ensures non null user list. 
                                    // now return "true" if any of the user has the same username. "false" otherwise
                                    if (any { username == it.username }) "true"
                                    else "false"
                                },
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

I hope the above example and explanation will help you understand how thing works. Feel free to ask if you still have confusion.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users likely does not support form POST and/or query by username; write your own REST API... because with that fake API, you could only check within the `.onResponse()` callback, if `String username` is contained in `Response<ArrayList<FakeUserModel>>`.

Comment: so, in your suggestion how to to check if `arrayList` contains `username`? please

Comment: You're not asking the API, when doing so - so this doesn't rmake much sense. I'm sure you can find or write such a simple method. And unless the API would return the requested username, this won't even be known at response time (those requests happen asynchronous).